# PHP - FTP Error Handling

Tags: php, error-handling, ftp, ftp-client

So, I'm creating an FTP client using PHP.

What I want is, if the upload fails (timed out, connection error, etc.), it will try to upload the file again in 1 minute, and if it fails again then try in 10 minuts, until it reached the maximum time to upload the file.

Let's say I have these files in my local folder:
`File1.ext, File2.ext, File3.ext`. And I successfully uploaded `File1.ext` and `File3.ext`. I should reupload the `File2.ext`, how should I do it? Any ideas?

I am running my script in the background using `exec()`, and if the upload is done, it will send me an email regarding the process. And I am doing recursive upload, it checks the files in my local folder then upload it one by one then deletes it after uploading.

Thanks!

Comment: You may create an empty array `$failure`, when an upload fails you add the file name/path to the array, at the end you loop through the array as much as you want ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I can do that. Should I write insert my code inside the a `while()` loop then if the local folder is empty, I'll just stop the loop? For how long can a script run? Or it won't stop until I terminate it, etc? Thanks :D

Comment: The default max time for a php script is 30 seconds, if you have full control of your server you may edit the configuration file or just use `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` in the top of your script (this will make the max time to unlimited, you may change the 0 to 300 for example 300sec = 5mn). When you're looping through the array, you may check if the array element is empty by using something like this `if(count($failure) == 0){ // done}`. Hmmmm, if the upload succeed in your loop, you have to delete it by using `unset()`.

Comment: Thanks for that! So, is it okay to enclose my script in a `while()` loop? And should I use `sleep()` to delay the execution of the next loop? Or there's a better way to do this stuff? Thanks!

Comment: As long you do a correct loop it's okay. I'm just thinking and then i though you may do some filtering, for example take a look at the [return codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes) if you got a reply **553** then it doesn't matter how much you "retry" it won't get uploaded, in this case you have to throw an error that the file didn't get uploaded because of... There are many situations and ways to handle this. For example make a list of codes, each code tells you to continue retrying or just stop and log an error. Also you may just limit the retry to 5 for ex.